# Understanding observables syntax and functionality

Tags: angular

I have the following method that returns an observable:

```
getRecipeInfo(): Observable<RecipeGlobal>{
         return this.http.get<RecipeGlobal>(this.searchUrl);
  }
```

what do the types in Observable and the http.get method mean in this context?. For http.get, I assume that's the type on which the response is parsed.

Comment: it basically means that your response should be of type RecipeGlobal model, which is returned by the observable function getRecipeInfo()

Comment: But that's already specified by this.http.get<RecipeGlobal>. why do I also have to specify it at the Observable level?

Comment: depends on how you want your function to perform...you are basically imposing your function to return an observable of such type.. you can even create it as any on the function level and it will not throw you any error

Comment: My understanding of observable is that you subscribe to it waiting for a value to be emitted and then be unsubscribed. Does the observable type correspond to the type of the emitted value?

Comment: well, you are wrong on the point that subsciption gets unsubscribed, you have to unsubscribe its yourself but yes, the observable type corresponds to the type of the emitted value, if it does not match the one that you strictly defined then it will throw error

Comment: I think the method inside the observable my default by default calls unsubscribe when it reaches the end of the flow.

Comment: oh nononono, I don't know what you are using for the function calls, but thats not the way observables are supposed to work, you either have to use the instance of subscription and destory it on ngDestroy, or use `takeUntil` or use `take` or use `effectDispatch`, else you will end up with bunch of memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

```
return this.http.get<RecipeGlobal>(this.searchUrl);
```

When called this way, the type of RecipeGlobal will be inferred as Observable. This is a compile-time type assertion. It informs TypeScript that the response’s content will have a shape compatible with the RecipeGlobal interface or class. However, at run time, the response’s content could be anything.